# To develop a testing tool

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests

Now, I am trying to develop a testing tool, which can make unit testing. I mean I want to use JUnit in my testing tool to test other projects. But I don't know how to insert JUnit into my testing tool. Is it possible to do that and how? And is there any other open-source testing tool can be inserted into my testing tool?

Comment: Well, typically in software, many things are possible. Of course, you could use JUnit functionality inside some other, self-written component. Probably this answer is not what you were looking for, but well: given your unspecific input; what did you expect? In other words: if you want more helpful, specific answers, then consider writing up questions that, well, contain "answerable" content. In that sense: please turn to the help center to understand how/what to ask here ...

Comment: well, I am trying to call the JUnit API in my testing tool, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To use Junit API make sure you got the jar in the classpath

To use Junit tests you need the testing class to extend SystemTestCase4
and your function to have @Test annotation above it 
if you want code to run before your test so use function with @Before
and if you want after use function with @After

```
public class BaseTest extends SystemTestCase4 {


@Before
public void beforeEachTest() throws Exception {

}

@Test
@TestProperties(name = "test test ")
public void testTest() throws Exception {
//run your tested code
}

@After
public void afterEachTest() throws Exception {

}
```

as for how to test your projects it depend what tests you want to do?
For unit testing just add your own tests inside the projects
Integration, Functional or other tests  need you to understand how to "Attack" it, meaning if it's UI tests for web so use tools for that (Selenium for example) if it's for checking network so use JMeter